# Word documents common style

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to have a set of word documents that have a common style and whenever that common style changes, all the docs get the new one?

Something like a master slide in powerpoint

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for involves using Word templates.

Try starting with these instructions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/save-a-word-document-as-a-template-HA010030754.aspx). You can save a template (.dot file) and then use that template for the "common" settings in new Word documents.

It sounds also like you want old documents to automatically get new formatting changes, when you say "all the docs get the new one." I don't think Word has this capability as an automatic feature (although it should).

[This page](http://addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) suggests the following workaround that should allow you to apply formatting changes to old documents on a case-by-case basis. I know it's not what you're after, but it's a start.

> If you want the layout features or text from the new template for your document, your best bet is to create a new document based on the new template and then copy the contents of your old document into the new document. Then close the old document and save your new document using the same name. Note that your new document will use style definitions from the template rather than from your old document.

Best of luck.